# Multiple docker-compose .dcproj in a Visual Studio solution

Tags: docker, visual-studio-2017, docker-compose

To develop some boilerplate code for a dockerized solution, I want to have multiple docker-compose .dcproj projects in the same solution.
Lets say:

1. **shared-docker-compose**.dcproj - *Shared services* for interop, like a MQ
2. **example-docker-compose**.dcproj - *Example services* for testing/playground for the boilerplate.
3. **app1-docker-compose**.dcproj - The actual *services for scenario 1*
4. **app#**...

This should keep the velocity in development high if a part of solution needs an update. And the developer is free to consider which part of the whole solution he wants to take a look at.

Okay - not really a problem to create this project/compose files. No problem with docker, docker-compose, or any other part of the solution. Except the IDE.

**Visual Studio 2017** truely struggles with multiple dcproj-files.

- The behavior is different based on the order of dcproj in the .sln-file.
- It takes the first found dcproj.
- Unloading all other dcproj helps. But I'm not sure if this is stable.
- Even if it starts, there's no guarantee the debugger tracking the requested composition. E.g. Starting dcproj#3, the debugger listens to dcproj#2.
- If the first found dcproj is just plain image distributor (Like start MQ, no code, thus no 'build:'), then the compose gets up but the dev is dumped in silence.
- Strangely, when there are multiple dcproj-files in the solution and you *Add -> Docker Support* you can choose which of them.

Or in a short: Not usable without a strong explanation to all developers. It even took a long time to get all those responsibility fragments together.

**So, here's my question:**
Is there any way for such a composition that works with Visual Studios .dcproj too?
Are there any recommendations for such a common scenario?

At the moment, the only way I've found was to split the solutions where the only difference is which docker-compose is included. Thank you for any ideas and for sharing your practices.

Btw, I'd like to add a dcproj-file tag. :)

Comment: Thanks for this. When you say, " the only way I've found was to split the solutions", do you mean multiple sln files in (presumably) the root folder which reference different sets of projects? Any issues with that?

Comment: Yes, multiple sln-files in the root folder. They can contain the same projects if you want to. Well, the only issue is the increased merge if you change any of those projects.
To avoid it, I'm currently using 1 sln, extracted the shared-compose to a PowerShell-Script and disabled all app-compose.dcproj except the one I'm currently developing

Comment: As of Visual Studio 16.5.3 it doesn't look like multiple docker-compose projects is supported. I added a feature request, https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1012698/support-multiple-docker-compose-projects-in-a-sing.html

Comment: I was able to create two docker-compose projects by renaming my first docker-compose project and its docker-compose files. After unloading that project the add "Container orchestrator support" option showed up again. I created a new docker-compose project and was able to reload the original, renamed project. But, it looks like renamed docker-compose projects/files is not supported because the renamed project is still using the original "docker-compose" file name.